# How do i specify to a model what to take as input of a custom loss function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, loss-function

I'm having issues in understanding/implementing a custom loss function in my model.

I have a keras model which is composed by 3 sub models as you can see here in the model architecture,

[image: model architecture]

Now, I'd like to use the outputs of *model* and *model_2* in my custom loss function.
I understand that in the loss function definition I can write:

```py
    def custom_mse(y_true, y_pred):
        *calculate stuff*
    return loss
```

But how do I tell **the model** to take its 2 outputs as inputs of the loss function?

Maybe, and i hope so, it's super trivial but I didn't find anything online, if you could help me it'd be fantastic.

Thanks in advance

**Context:**
*model* and *model_2* are the same pretrained model, a binary classifier, which predicts the interaction between 2 inputs (of image-like type).
*model_1* is a generative model which will edit one of the inputs.

Therefore:

```py
    complete_model = Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2], outputs=[out_model, out_model2])
    opt = *an optimizer*
    
    complete_model.compile(loss=custom_mse,
                           ??????,
                           optimizer = opt,
                           metrics=['whatever'])
```

The main goal is to compare the prediction with the edited input against the one with the un-edited input, therefore the model will outputs the 2 interactions, which i need to use in the loss function.

**EDIT:**
Thank you Andrey for the solution,

Now however i can't manage to implement together the 2 loss functions, namely the one with add_loss(func) and a classic binary_crossentropy in model.complie(loss='binary_crossentropy', ...).

Can I maybe add an add_loss specifying model_2.output and the label? If yes do you know how?

They work by themselves but not together, when i try to run the code they raise

`ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 0 and 4 From merging shape 0 with other shapes. for '{{node AddN}} = AddN[N=2, T=DT_FLOAT](binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/value, complete_model/generator/tf_op_layer_SquaredDifference_3/SquaredDifference_3)' with input shapes: [], [?,500,400,1].`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add loss with `compile()` only for standard loss function signature (y_true, y_pred). You can not use it because your signature is something like (y_true, (y_pred1, y_pred2)). Use `add_loss()` API instead. See here: https://keras.io/api/losses/